# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in flash in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am having a `ValueError (ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2))` in my `Flask` App. I came to know that this is because of flash that I am using to display a message with a category in it.

The problem occurs, when I try this

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for category, msg in messages %}

      <div class="alert {{category}}">
        <h1>{{category}}:</h1>
        <h4>{{msg}}</h4>
      </div>

    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

But if I just remove the category from the for loop it works, but the category doesn't!

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for msg in messages %}

      <div class="alert {{category}}">
        <h1>{{category}}:</h1>
        <h4>{{msg}}</h4>
      </div>

    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Please help me

Comment: Could you post how `messages` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out what to do, the problem was I had to mention that I want to use the category in jinja

> {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(**with_categories=true**) %}

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} 
  {% if messages %} 
     {% for category, msg in messages %}
        <div class="alert {{category}}">
          <h4>{{msg}}</h4>
        </div>
     {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 2):

i guess you're missing to set the second parameter, the category of the message (it could be `error`, `warning` whatever ..) for `flash()` in your view function

```
flash(u'Invalid password provided', 'error')
```

don't forget to set `with_categories=true` in `get_flashed_messages()` function:

```html
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {# --HERE--  #}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for category, msg in messages %}

      <div class="alert {{category}}">
        <h1>{{category}}:</h1>
        <h4>{{msg}}</h4>
      </div>

    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

refer to this [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/#flashing-with-categories)